# How to search a tag value of XML file in Unix?

Tags: shell, unix, xml-parsing

I have an xml like below

```
<productCode>
    <codingScheme>BDR</codingScheme>
</productCode>
<productCode>
    <codingScheme>CNY</codingScheme>
</productCode>
...
<riskCategoryCode>
    <codingScheme>BDR</codingScheme>
</riskCategoryCode>
<riskCategoryCode>
    <codingScheme>NCP</codingScheme>
</riskCategoryCode>
...
```

Now I need to count how many such *BDR* values are there for `codingScheme` under `productCode` tag only.

I wrote this script:

```
Word1="<productCode>";
Word2="<codingScheme>BDR";
Word3="$Word1${Var}$Word2";
echo "$Word3";
grep -c "$Word3" fileFullName;
```

But it counts the total occurences of `productCode` and `codingScheme` (eg. `productCode` 10 times and `codingScheme` 20 times then it returns 30 which is not required).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{if($0~/\<codingScheme\>BDR\<\/codingScheme\>/){if(x~/productCode/)count++};x=$0}END{print count}' your_file
```

tested:

```
> cat temp
<productCode>
<codingScheme>BDR</codingScheme>
</productCode>
<productCode>
<codingScheme>CNY</codingScheme>
</productCode>
<productCode>
<codingScheme>BDR</codingScheme>
</productCode>
......
<riskCategoryCode>
<codingScheme>BDR</codingScheme>
</riskCategoryCode>
<riskCategoryCode>
<codingScheme>NCP</codingScheme>
</riskCategoryCode>
> awk '{if($0~/\<codingScheme\>BDR\<\/codingScheme\>/){if(x~/productCode/)count++};x=$0}END{print count}' temp
2
>
```